# Have multiple type implementations but only have one of them active based on condition in Typescript

Tags: typescript, interface, conditional-types

Trying to figure out how can I make compiler to not to error when the given type has multiple implementations and only one of them is active at any given time.

For example I have following two interfaces:

```js
interface fooA {
kind: 'fooA',
a: string,
b: string
c: string
}

interface fooB {
kind: 'fooB',
c: string
d: string,
e: string
}

export type IFoo = fooA | fooB
```

now one of my method is dealing with this props passed in as arguments, and at any given time only one of these both interface would be valid and I want typescript to only detect types for currently active interface inside condition.
So it will look something like this...

```js
someClass {
  constructor(foo: IFoo){

    switch(foo.kind){
      case 'fooA': {
        // do something with params 
        console.log(`${foo.a}-${foo.b}-${foo.c}`)
        break;
      }
      case 'fooB': {
        // do something with params 
        console.log(`${foo.c}-${foo.d}-${foo.e}`)
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So with this implementation I get error saying... 

 `Property 'a' does not exist on type 'foo'.
  Property 'a' does not exist on type 'fooB'.ts(2339)`

which seems pretty clear that `fooB` does not have property `a` but is it possible to configure multiple condition based interfaces with typescript, so interface `fooA` is active inside first case and `fooB` is active inside second case.

Comment: Your code works correctly. The two interfaces in your first snippet are called `fooA`.

Comment: is the re-declaration of `fooA` a typo? Other than that, this is working code in TypeScript.

Comment: yes, it is a typo, I meant to put fooB there

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so others can see what you're talking about.  [Your code above](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAhgezQQWQbwFDLIDWoAJgFzIDk6WVANAcnJQM5hSgDmjhARmw7cmCQZxBc8AXzx5QkWIhS0AQriYkQFaqoYixwwtvbieTCAYnTZEAB4AHNFDDIwAT3soAkgDEMyAF5UDGwAH2C0FVkEABs4VlZkVjQAWwgAYTiE9UIENBATAFcEMCcAClpKXwwASnUmQlYAd2AwBAALZAqMADpNUjr8QmHkBHiUGhCqSiGR4YB6eeRSNCTUiDB27mQWzeR7OCg4FMSGubyCtBiIHpi0LjKAAwASHFoeuCkAWlf3vm-fr0EFJHjUziM+FAIHAiABucHIGRzUbjHQYFTTHLI5CLZarZJpTbbXadA5HE7IBG5fLJa63e5PQFoHrAn5vXqkAHs5kQEFg7HISHQuEIpHDMUyKRAA) compiles just fine.

Comment: Okay, so I think I have figured out the problem. Problem was that I was similar structure as above but had a typo in case. 
Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use one of the methods outlined in the Typescript documentation regarding [Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).

Using *type predicates*, or by using `typeof`, `instanceof` or `in`, Typescript can evaluate conditions to narrow the possible types of a variable.

Comment: I have tried some of type guards but not sure how to it get to work with scenario presented.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I think I have figured out the problem. Problem was that I had similar structure as above but had a typo in case statement. I guess one more reason for not doing direct string comparison.
Thanks everyone